# search result page sidebar missing

Tags: magento2

It seems like I am missing the sidebar on my search result page, for more detail refer to the image below. How do I add the same sidebar that, I have on the category page?

I have tried adding widgets but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

most likely this is because of the "sidebar" or "sidebar.additional" container has been removed from your theme layout.

In order to fix this issue, please follow the steps below:

Look for `remove="true"` in the theme `layout XML files`. For this you need to check out all these files in our theme in general:

```
app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/themename/*/layout/*.xml
```

Remove or comment lines that look like this

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true" />
```

or

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar" remove="true" />
```

hope this will solve your issue